# Possibility regarding elastic beanstalk and teamcity

Tags: amazon-web-services, teamcity, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently set up teamcity for continuous integration of my website.  It builds the site every time there is a check-in on git hub.

Now, I would like to set up an automatic deployment process so that the site automatically deploys to elastic beanstalk after being built.

After doing some research and not finding too much, I wanted to ask:

1) is this even possible? and
2) how would I go about doing it?